# Listview's item changed while listview scrolling in android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I set up `adapter` for `ListView` and in my `inflaterLayout` i put more one `TextView` to display Category, and when i get same category name that time i hide `Textview` from `ListView` and when i get the different category that time i set visible for `TextView`, so now i get perfect data but when i am trying to scroll the `ListView` that time each row changed automatically,

So what is the solution for it to prevent the changes the position of list items?

If you have any idea related to it, than please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't understand what changes. Is it the content inside ListView's rows or the rows order?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more the setup of your ListView? As it stands right now, your question is very hard to understand. Maybe posting some code would help?

Comment: if you put if.... VISIBLE, you also must put else...INVISIBLE

Comment: Finally i got Solution for this question: if(convertView == null){   }else{  holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.tv_category_name.setText("");
    holder.tv_subcategory_name.setText("");}

Answer (score 0):

Don't add any view at getView(). Instead, add the other TextView before, and set its visibilty to be 'gone'. At getView() check if you need this view, if so, set its visibility to be 'visible' otherwise, set 'gone ' (you must set the visibilty for every list item even if you believe that you don't have to do so).